# how to extract url id from string with regex?

Tags: javascript

suppose that, i've this string:

`google.com/:id/:category`

how can i extract only id and category from this string?

i should use regex

this match doesn't work:

`match(/\/:([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/g);`

Comment: Explain why it doesn't work, because it should work.

Comment: because response is: `(2) ['/:id', '/:category']` but i need `['id', category]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try the following:

```js
var url = "google.com/:id/:category";
var parts = url.match(/(?<=\/:)[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g);
console.log(parts);
```

This approach uses the positive lookbehind `(?<=\/:)` to get around the problem of matching the unwanted leading `/:` portion.  Instead, this leading marker is asserted but not matched in the version above.

Answer (score 2):

Well, capture groups are ignored in match with `/g`. You might go with [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) like this:

```js
const url = "google.com/:id/:category"
const info = [...url.matchAll(/\/:([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/g)].map(match => match[1])
console.log(info)
```

Credit:  [Better access to capturing groups (than String.prototype.match())](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#better_access_to_capturing_groups_than_string.prototype.match)